# Laravel checking common column through lots of nested relationships in query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm working on a Laravel 10 project. I have a query that has at least 4 or 5 relationships that I need to join. Some of these contain a boolean called `is_enabled`. What's the best way to cascade check each relationship?

For exxample, in this piece of code, I need to check my `pingtree_group` and `pingtree_group_entries`, if I wanted to check the `is_enabled` on a `buyer_tier`, would I have to deeply continue nesting my `whereHas`?

```php
$app = Application::with([
    'modelable',
    'pingtree_group' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_enabled', true)
                ->whereHas('pingtree_group_entries', function ($q) {
                    $q->where('is_enabled', true);
                });
    },
    'pingtree_group.pingtree_group_entries.pingtree.pingtree_entries.buyer_tier'
])->where('id', 30)
    ->first();
```